# JWT from AzureAD gives 403 Forbidden in .NET core API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, jwt

I have an asp.net core API that works with JWT authentication. Roles are used for authorization, I use no scopes. Things work fine with both Auth0.com and ADFS, I am having trouble however with AzureAD. I get a JWT from AzureAD, which looks fine. However, then this happens:

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler[2]
      Successfully validated the token.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler[8]
      AuthenticationScheme: Bearer was successfully authenticated.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService[2]
      Authorization failed.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler[13]
      AuthenticationScheme: Bearer was forbidden.
```

I am at a loss as to what is the cause of this. Also, I am having a hard time getting more details as *why* authorization fails.

The only difference I see between a JWT from for example Auth0.com and AAD, is the lack of a "azp" claim, and the lack of a "scope" claim. The token from AAD has a "scp" claim. However, I am unable to find any documentation about wether this could result in this situation, or if something else could be the cause.

Any ideas, also about how to get more details, are welcome! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meanwhile I was able to solve this issue. For future reference I am posting the solution here.

There is a "roles" claim in the access token that comes from AAD, but for reasons rather unclear to me, with AAD as an identity provider, I have to check for "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role" as the role claim.

This code works for both Auth0, ADFS and AAD:

```
var roleClaim = Configuration["JwtOptions:RoleClaim"];
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(roleClaim)) roleClaim = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role";
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("role1", policy => policy.RequireClaim(roleClaim, "role1", "role2"));
    options.AddPolicy("role2", policy => policy.RequireClaim(roleClaim, "role2"));
});
```

If someone can shed some light on why this is so, I'd be very interested. For now, I'm happy to have solved this.

Comment: Sidenote: instead of hardcoding the roleclaim, it may be better to do:
`if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(roleClaim)) roleClaim = ClaimTypes.Role;`

Comment: A last note: [this page] (https://mderriey.com/2019/06/23/where-are-my-jwt-claims/) explains the cause of the issue very clearly.